# Unable to set the curl's "User" Parameter in RestAssured

Tags: rest-assured

I'm trying to port the following curl shell in a RestAssured Test:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token \
    --user backend-service:secret \
    -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    -d 'username=alice&password=alice&grant_type=password'
```

Here is my RestAssured version:

```
response = given().urlEncodingEnabled(true)
        .auth().basic("backend-service", "secret")
        .param("grant_type", "password")
        .param("client_id", "backend-service")
        .param("username", "alice")
        .param("password", "alice")
        .header("Accept", ContentType.JSON.getAcceptHeader())
        .post("http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token")
        .then().statusCode(200).extract()
        .response();
```

Unfortunately, the problem is the "--user" parameter, which is not translated through the auth().basic(). From the server log I can see it's the only parameter that it's null:

```
type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=demo, clientId=backend-service, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_client_credentials, grant_type=password
```

Any idea how to configure it ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `.auth().preemptive()`?

Comment: Thanks, auth().preemptive() did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use regular authentication (aka pre-emptive authentication - e.g. how Curl does it)::

```java
response = given().urlEncodingEnabled(true)
        .auth().preemptive().basic("backend-service", "secret")
        ...
```

More information you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51240654/11089623)